# Display Checkbox items in Dropdown list (MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

My checkbox items works very well. however, I need to display it as dropdown list

here's the list in the **BookViewModel.cs** (the model displayed in my view)

```
public List<CheckBoxViewModel> Authors { get; set; }
```

this is The **CheckBoxViewModel.cs**

```
  public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

This my controller (which adds the items into the **Authors** in **checkboxViewModel**

```
 var Results = from b in db.author
                      select new
                      {
                          b.authorID,
                          name = b.first_name + " " + b.middle_name + " " + b.last_name,

                      };
        var MyViewModel = new BooksViewModel();

        var MyCheckBoxList = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in Results)
        {
            MyCheckBoxList.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel { Id = item.authorID, Name = item.name});
        }

        MyViewModel.Authors = MyCheckBoxList;
```

and finally this is how i display the checkbox items in my view **Create.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Authors, ": المؤلف/ المؤلفين", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div style="text-align:right">
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Authors.Count(); i++)
                            {

                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Authors[i].Name) <text> </text>
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Authors[i].Checked)

                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Authors[i].Name)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Authors[i].Id)
                                <br />
                            }
                        </div>
                        <text class="text-danger"> @ViewBag.empty_authors</text>
                        @Html.ActionLink("مؤلف جديد ", "CreateAuthor", "books", new { Model }, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-success", @style = "font-size:20px" })<br />
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.authorID, new SelectList(ViewBag.authorID, "a_id", "fullname"), htmlAttributes: new { @multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })*@



                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Authors, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

pleaese note that I don't use any JQuery / scripts till in my code till now, if there's any way to display the checkbox items in dropdownlist using C# in my controller it'll be preferable

Thank you .

*PS. if there's a solution using JavaScripts please describe it in details.*

---

**EDIT :** 
I decided to fix the height of the div that contains my list of Authors in **Create.cshtml** view and I allow it to be scroll-able in y-axis, i find it an acceptable solution for my problem so no need for **extra javascript code** .

Comment: Not unless you find a suitable jquery plugin or write you own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't, you will have to find a jquery plugin to do so.